# Rebuilding a container in Dokku causes an error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dokku

So I'm trying to rebuild my container but it returns:

Error response from daemon: Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB

After typing htop on my ubuntu server this is what Im receiving:

```
CONTAINER ID    NAME        CPU %    MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %    NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS    
X               X.web.1     0.02%    695.2MiB / 11.73GiB   5.79%    246MB / 382MB       22.2MB / 39.2MB     271
```

While having this on a test server it is taking:

```
CONTAINER ID    NAME        CPU      MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %    NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
X               X.web       0.01%    125.9MiB / 7.796GiB   1.58%    1.12MB / 4.48MB     26.9MB / 393kB      257
```

Any idea what I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a resource limit via the resources plugin? If so, you may have it configured incorrectly. See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/resource-management/ for usage docs on that module if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
dokku resource:limit-clear appname
```

worked for me